# jQuery - Can the show() function return true?

Tags: jquery

I have make a script by using jQuery such as :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[name=pmRead]').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var pmtext=$(this).parents(".pmMain").find(".pmMain5");
    });         
});
```

Now, I'd like to use a function like pmtext.show() and get TRUE if the element is visible. Else, I'd like to return FALSE. Any change to get TRUE/FALSE by using show()? (or the sister function hide()).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a function to check the visibility, but it is not `show()/hide()`.

```
if (pmtext.is(':visible')) {
    // ....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not use the following:

```
pmtext.is(":visible");
```

That will provide a boolean true if it is visible and false if it is not.  For the converse you can use `pmtext.is(":hidden");`.

If you want to do something on visible, try:

```
$(this).parents(".pmMain").find(".pmMain5:visible").hide();  // only finds it if visible
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest writing a custom function if you need to return true or false.

```
function customShow(element)
{
    if( $( element ).is( ':visible' ) )
        return true;

    $( element ).show();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: But `$(element).is(":visible")` already returns true or false - why wrap it?

Comment: Fair point — the only reason to wrap it would be to perform other actions based on the visibility of that element.

Comment: for that can't you use the `:visible` selector?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own simple function, to check if its visible or not.

Note: The function takes a jQuery element as input.

```
function isVisible($element) {
   return $element.css("display").toLowerCase() != "none");
}
```

Comment: why inventing the wheel? `$(element).is(':visible')` does just that!

Comment: There's already `.is(":visible")` and the `:visible` selector.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the .[toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method?  It optionally accepts a "showOrHide" argument.

Answer (score 0):

`<script language="JavaScript">`

`function menu(bolum) {`

`if ( bolum.style.display =='none')
 { bolum.style.display='';islem.style.display='';} else {bolum.style.display='none';}
}`

`</script>`

`<img src="images/biz-arayalim.png" onclick="menu(firmamesajkutusu)" style="cursor:pointer;">`
`<div name="firmamesajkutusu" id="firmamesajkutusu"></div>`

Old system javascript all div kontrol function